# How to use reload without validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm setting up basic tests for a rails app, I'm wondering how the reload function works. Rails generated the basic crud tests, I adapted them to my need, but it seems like the `reload` function doesn't work.

I create a user with valid params, then ask to change its name, but it seems like nothing's updated (output is still name: 'Toto' instead of name: 'Tata').

Here's the code sample, I just followed the basic rspec tutorial, still, nothing gets updated. Any idea why ?

```
context "with valid params" do
  let(:new_attributes) { {name: 'Tata'} }

  it "updates the requested creator" do
    creator = Creator.create! valid_attributes
    puts creator.id
    puts new_attributes
    put :update, :id => creator.id, :creator => new_attributes
    creator.reload
    puts creator.name.to_yaml
    expect(creator.attributes).to include( { "name" => 'Tata' } )
    ...
```

Here's the matching controller method

def update
    @creator = Creator.find(params[:id])

```
authorize @creator
@creator.completed = true
params[:hidden] == 'false' ? @creator.hidden = false : @creator.hidden = true
@creator.update(creator_params)


if params[:user].present?
  if params[:user][:picture].present?
    @creator.picture = params[:user][:picture]
  end
end


if @creator.save
  if iban.nil? || (iban && !iban.valid?)
    flash[:alert] = "Veuillez entrer un IBAN valide"
    redirect_to edit_creator_path(@creator)
  elsif params[:brief_id].present?
    flash[:notice] = "Informations mises à jour"
    redirect_to brief_path(params[:brief_id])
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Informations mises à jour"
    redirect_to creator_path(@creator)
  end
else
  puts @creator.errors.full_messages
  render :edit
end
end
```

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: why aren't you doing your expectation directly on the attribute? `expect(creator.name).to eq("Tata")`

Comment: @DMH just added the matching controller method

Comment: Does the controller code actually reach the `@creator.save` part?

Comment: I don't think so, else it would probably change the name. I don't think pundit would conflict with Rspec either